# Array Return to subset

Tags: ruby

This is part of a script I was working on which definitely returns and array, but I would like the result to be in `[[:a, :c].to_set,[:b,:c].to_set].to_set` and not `[[:c, :b], [:c, :a]]`.

```
@potentially_alive = Array.new
if (self_defended?(s))
    @potentially_alive.delete_if { |pa| pa.subset?(s.to_set)}
    @potentially_alive.push(s.to_set)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your currently result is
`[[:a, :c], [:b, :c]]`

and you would like to to change it to
`[[:a, :c].to_set, [:b, :c].to_set]`

You can to the following (if `@potentially_alive = [[:a, :c], [:b, :c]]`):

`@potentially_alive.map! { |a| a.to_set }`
or
`@potentially_alive = @potentially_alive.map { |a| a.to_set }`

Comment: sorry where will either of this solution replace